# Использование команд при запущеном сервере на node js

Tags: node.js, терминал

Запускаю сервер на nodejs и терминал получается начинает работать в режиме сервера, могу ли я как то использовать его чтобы взаимодействовать с сервером. Ну то есть сейчас он просто выводит то что console.log() у меня в server.js. А как писать какие либо команды серверу. Вызвать функцию например. В поисковиках даже не знаю как свою вопрос задать.

Использую модули socket.io и express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно читать открытый, командной строкой, стрим. Это можно сделать с помощью модуля [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). Из вашего вопроса не понятно, как именно вы хотите взаимодействовать с сервером.
Привожу мини пример из документации ниже:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (input) => {
    console.log(input);
});
```